# Why does the AWS SES developer guide recommend using stunnel with Postfix?

Tags: amazon-web-services, postfix, stunnel, amazon-ses

I swear they changed this in the last year or two, but as of 2017-11-20, the [SES developer guide for Postfix](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html) recommends setting up TLS via stunnel. This seems odd to me, considering that Postfix can already do TLS if you just add these lines to `main.cf`:

```
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

In fact, I'm pretty sure I originally got the above configuration options from a previous version of the SES docs. Why did they change this?

Comment: I recall recently seeing that and wondering the same thing, since as you point out, it's unnecessary.  Stranger still, I see no reference to stunnel on that page at the moment.  Check it again?  Maybe some old content got inadvertently published and subsequently reverted.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I just checked the page again, and you're right! The stunnel stuff is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

It could be realted to

> Postfix < 3.0 Although older Postfix SMTP client versions do not
>   support TLS wrapper mode, it is relatively easy to forward a
>   connection through the stunnel program if Postfix needs to deliver
>   mail to some legacy system that doesn't support STARTTLS.

But you can avoid of using stunnel with postfix 3.0+

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_wrappermode

Also according to the http://www.postfix.org/announcements/postfix-3.1.4.html only 2.11 currently supported (as legacy release) from 2.x branches

Comment: TLS negotiation seems to fail when ```smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes```, at least on FreeBSD 13.1 When I comment this line out, everything seems to just work. 

So I wondered the same thing, why use this in the first place ? Is it just because some legacy writeup like https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/freebsd-configure-aws-ses-with-postfix-mta/